# Does qgis2web have a max amount of characters

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis2web

I am trying to make a webmap with points and if you click on those point you get information about the location. Everything works in QGIS, but when I want to export it to a webpage my point doesn't show. When I delete a few sentences from my CSV file it does show up on the webpage.

Does it have a certain amount of letters / words you can use for it to work?

Comment: So how long are the comments? Can you provide a bit more information: you export as Leaflet or Openlayers? Does your text contain any special characters?

Comment: If you follow the specific bullet points in the debugging instructions which tell you to use the QGIS Python console and your browser's JS console, you should get more precise details of what the porblem is. See https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web#reporting-bugs.